# Sass, give parents same styles as childs

Tags: sass

As i'm new to sass I haven't found a way to use the same rules on the parents when nesting stuff. The example below show a basic example, I know that you can use @extend for this but is there a cleaner way to do this?

looking for

```
.table,
.table th,
.table td{
    background:#000;
}
```

sass

```
.table{
    background:#000;

    th,
    td{
       background:#000;//repating
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ampersand (&) selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) to reference the parent selector, like so:

```
.table {
    &,
    th,
    td {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```